# Class alert when section's top is equal or higher than main panel's top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a fixed panel with its content scrolled and separated by divs. I would, when any  content's div TOP reaches panel TOP, an alert to appear with that div's class.

Each div has a class like this `<div class="section-proceso anc1">` (both classes included on each div start with `section-` and `anc`, if needed ant new class can be added)

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/5007/)

I have tried things like this with no result:

```
if ($("div[class^='anc']").offset().top >= $('.contentPanel').offset().top){
   alert($(this).attr('class'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(".contentPanel").scroll(function () {
    $("div[class*='anc']").each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var TopView = $('.contentPanel').offset().top;
        var TopElement = $this.offset().top;
        if (TopElement <= TopView && !$(this).hasClass('Appear')){
            $(this).addClass('Appear');
            alert($(this).attr('class'));
        }

        if (TopElement >= TopView && $(this).hasClass('Appear')){
            $(this).removeClass('Appear');
            alert($(this).attr('class'));
        }
    });
});
```

You never see the `alert` for last section becuase you mention that "when any content's div TOP reaches panel TOP, an alert to appear with that div's class." and top of last section never reaches to top of panel.

Note: The `Appear` class is used to prevent repeated alert on every scroll, you see the alert only when reach to a section and when you reach to the end of section the `Appear` class has been removed, so you see the alert only when reach to a section from top or bottom and don't see a repeated annoying alert when scroll a section form up to down or reverse.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/5011/)**

Comment: I am very sorry about the delay, I could not check anything till today. Very grateful, worked.

Comment: I already marked it yesterday, you can see it checkd up on green!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to fire your code each time the scroll happens, so put it in the container's scroll event handler.
2. In your selector, you are checking for class attribute which have values like `section-proceso anc1`, `section-proceso anc2`, and so on. none of which starts with 'anc'. So you either have to change them to `anc1 section-proceso` or use the `contains` selector (`*`).
3. For the div to reach upto or above the container use 'less than or equal to' (`<=`) comparator and not 'greater than or equal to' (`>=`).

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".contentPanel").scroll(function(){
        $("div[class*='anc']").each(function(){
            if ($(this).offset().top <= $('.contentPanel').offset().top)
               console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/5009/